# Using gdal to interpolate elevation from a GeoTIFF

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, interpolation, elevation

I am new to GDAL and am looking for pointers about the Correct™ way to accomplish a few tasks. I would like to do this in Python, not on the command line.

I have a GeoTIFF that shows elevation at 10m intervals over a given area. That is, every pixel is a 10m x 10m area. The GeoTIFF contains a single raster image, where elevation in meters is expressed as a Float32. The GeoTIFF seems to have tags defining the geoid/datum (which UTM zone etc).

I wish to open that image, and query what the elevation is at a certain point, such as in the following pseudocode:

`elevation = myGeoTiffData.getValueAtPosition(Position('WGS84', 39.584588, -122.461320))`

Further, I would like to have this elevation interpolated (linearly, spline-wise, however else) if the requested position does not fall on a 10m x 10m lattice point. I see there are some functions to do this (GDAL grid?), but I do not understand how to use them in this case.

I have tried to read the GDAL documentation, but I can't seem to figure this out. Is there any advice people here can offer?

Answer (score 7):

A high-level [rasterstats](https://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/) tool is built on GDAL to fetch data from raster and vector data sources.

```
import rasterstats
from shapely.geometry import Point

raster = "elevation.tif"
pt = Point(245000, 1000000)

# default is interpolate="bilinear"
elev = rasterstats.point_query([pt], raster)[0]

# or use nearest
elev = rasterstats.point_query([pt], raster, interpolate="nearest")[0]
```

Transformations to/from lat/long coordinates can be done using [pyproj](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/).

Answer (score 5):

rioxarray has an interpolation method that will work really well for this. See the details here https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/interpolate_na.html

```
import rioxarray

raster_file = './elevation.tif'

ds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(raster_file)
point_elevation = ds.interp(x= -122.461320, y= 39.584588, method='linear')
```

Comment: Is xarray aware of coordinate systems? Does it read the crs from the GeoTIFF tags?

Comment: @user30184 Yeah, it looks like xarray.open_rasterio and the newer rioxarray.open_rasterio use the rasterio library which does a bunch of nice GISsy things.

Answer (score 2):

[`gdallocationinfo`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdallocationinfo.html) is a utility for getting a value from a raster band or bands given a point location. However it does not do interpolation. I would recommend resampling to a higher resolution with an appropriate resampling algorithm. [`gdalwarp`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html) is the standard GDAL tool for this, and includes several [resampling algorithms](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-r) but it is up to you to choose the appropriate one.

I'm unaware of any GDAL tool that can do an on-the-fly continuous point interpolation.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to do this all in Python, so I can do various computations on the data. I will update my question to reflect that